# Starting a d3 axis timescale from zero

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm creating a graph that uses a time scale. I'd like the X axis to show times starting from zero, and counting up in intervals of 5 seconds each.

```
--------------------------------
:00  :05  :10  :15  :20  :25  :30
```

My data has timestamps, which are coerced to date objects. The scales are based on those timestamps.

(Note: I'm using d3 v4/5).

D3 has a nifty function for displaying time intervals, but the intervals start from the time in the data objects.

I could convert my data so all the times start on zero, but it would create additional problems as I'm lining up multiple datasets along the same timescale. I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to use one of the tick formatting functions for displaying ticks that are different than the scale or to calculate on the fly to start from zero seconds.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is a more completed code snippet.

```js
var videoData = [{
    "id": "1",
    "user_id": "_jlxvt8445494296",
    "video_id": "test",
    "time": "2018-09-11 15:39:20",
    "metric": "4"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "user_id": "_jlxvt8445494296",
    "video_id": "test",
    "time": "2018-09-11 15:39:26",
    "metric": "2"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "user_id": "_jlxvt8445494296",
    "video_id": "test",
    "time": "2018-09-11 15:39:27",
    "metric": "3"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "user_id": "_jlxvt8445494296",
    "video_id": "test",
    "time": "2018-09-11 15:39:38",
    "metric": "1"
  }
];

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = 400,
  height = 200;

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

//coerce to d3 timeParse object
videoData.forEach(function(d) {
  d.time = parseTime(d.time);
});

var x = d3.scaleTime()
  .rangeRound([0, width])
  .domain(d3.extent(videoData, function(d) {
    return d.time;
  }));

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .rangeRound([height, 0])
  .domain(d3.extent(videoData, function(d) {
    return d.metric;
  }));


var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.time);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.metric);
  })
  .curve(d3.curveBasis);


svg.append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(10," + height + ")")
 .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat(":%S")));

svg.append("path")
  .datum(videoData)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
  .attr("d", line);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg width="420" height="220"></svg>
```

Comment: It sounds like you want your x axis to represent relative time, rather than absolute time—is that correct? It'd be helpful if you gave examples of your multiple datasets, because I believe the problem is just how to standardise them and should be fairly easily solved by using different scales.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The project is data from multiple users watching a video, and recording reactions as the video plays. Each row has a timestamp of when the reaction was recorded. But, the records are not at regular intervals for all users. Some wait a few seconds, others record data once a second.

I'm graphing them all as line charts.

Comment: Can you add data for multiple users, since that's the problem you're dealing with here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do the calculations all relative to the start of the video.

Calculate the time difference in `ms` relative to the start of the video and convert that ms-time to a date `new Date(ms)`. You get the ms-time of a Date with `datevar.getTime()`.

To get past the timezone you have to do all display of the time in UTC.

Below an axis that displays the time from 00:00 to 01:40, the first 100 seconds with every 5 seconds a tick.

```js
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");//2018-09-10 21:06:34

var formatSecond = d3.utcFormat(":%S"),
    formatMinute = d3.utcFormat("%M:%S");

function multiFormat(date) {
  return (d3.timeMinute(date) < date ? formatSecond : formatMinute)(date);
}

var width = 500;
var height = 100;
var g = d3.select("#chart").append("svg").attr("width", width + 40).attr("height", height + 40)
          .append("g").attr("transform", "translate(20,20)");

var x = d3.scaleUtc()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    //.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.time; }));
    .domain([new Date(0), new Date(100*1000)]);

g.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  //.call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(d3.timeSecond.every(5)));
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(d3.utcSecond.every(5)).tickFormat(multiFormat));
```

```html
<script src='http://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js' charset='utf-8'></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that. The latest version of d3 has some new time functions, so I can offset all of the times in my data by finding the earliest time, and then using `d3.timeSecond.offset(data.time, 0-(earliestTime.getSeconds()))` But it seems hackish to convert all of the times in the data. Plus, I'd like to add more features with the time data, and keeping the integrity seems more beneficial. I was hoping there were some secrets in the axis formatting functions to offset time.

Comment: @jrue you can modify the `multiFormat` function and perform what ever you want with the supplied `date`, but then you have to supply the `ticks` yourself relative to the start time

Comment: Thanks, this gives me something to work on. Unfortunately, changing the scale would not longer allow my data to adhere to the graph. My fault, I should have included a more complete code snippet. I've updated my original post. Thanks for this, however. I'm playing around with your `multiFormat` function to see if I can offset the display of the data.

Comment: @jrue: You need to change the data, set the times relative to the start of the video, the absolute time is irrelevant, or add an additional (calculated) field that is the delta time